# in C++ what does this code means?

Tags: c++

I was working on linked lists and found a sample. In that sample it says

`while (currNode && index > currIndex)`

so here, whats the boolean value of currNode?

Comment: It depends on the type of `currNode`. What type it has affects what the conversion to `bool` caused by using it in a logical AND expression means.

Comment: Types. We need types. Everything in C++ is about the Types. What are the type of `currNode`, `index` and `currIndex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It most likely means `currNode != NULL`.

In `C++` everything not `0` (thus including everything not `NULL`) is considered `true` in boolean contexts.

Answer (score 1):

currNode is true if currNode is not a pointer to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

This code means something like this (in pseudo-C++)

```
while (/* if currNode is integer type */
       currNode != NULL &&
       /* if operator int() is defined */
       currNode.(operator int()) != 0 && 
       /* if operator bool() is defined */
       currNode.(operator bool()) != false && 
       /* or some other defined cast operators */
       index > currIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is checking that currNode is not null

```
while(currNode !=NULL && index > currIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

do something while currNode is != 0 and currNode is less than index

Comment: SO if I write "while(x)" in some code, is that means "work the code between while brackets till x = 0".